# Aurelia CLI - getting a stubborn client dependency to load correctly (and play nicely)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I've been banging my head against my keyboard for the better part of 3 hours trying to get this to work... i'm posting it to Stack as a last ditch effort to move forward.

I can not for the life of me get either Noble or Bleat ( Widely used BLE libs) to load correctly using the Aurelia CLI packager.

Here is my abridged aurelia.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "type": "project:application",
  "platform": {
    "id": "web",
    "displayName": "Web",
    "output": "scripts",
    "index": "index.html",
    "baseDir": "."
  },
  "transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
  },
  "markupProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".html",
    "source": "src/**/*.html"
  },
  "cssProcessor": {
    "id": "stylus",
    "displayName": "Stylus",
    "fileExtension": ".styl",
    "source": "src/**/*.styl"
  },
  "editor": {
    "id": "vscode",
    "displayName": "Visual Studio Code"
  },
  "unitTestRunner": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None"
  },
  "paths": {
    "root": "src",
    "resources": "resources",
    "elements": "resources/elements",
    "attributes": "resources/attributes",
    "valueConverters": "resources/value-converters",
    "bindingBehaviors": "resources/binding-behaviors"
  },
  "build": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "id": "web",
        "displayName": "Web",
        "output": "scripts",
        "index": "index.html",
        "baseDir": "."
      }
    ],
    "loader": {
      "type": "require",
      "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
      "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "extensions": [
            ".html",
            ".css"
          ],
          "stub": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "options": {
      "minify": "stage & prod",
      "sourcemaps": "dev & stage"
    },
    "bundles": [
      {
        "name": "app-bundle.js",
        "source": [
          "[**/*.js]",
          "**/*.{css,html}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
          "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird.js",
          "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
        ],
        "dependencies": [
          "aurelia-binding",
          "async",
          "rest-of-deps-here",
          {
            "name": "noble",
            "path": "../node_modules/noble/lib/noble"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And a snippet of a typical error.

```
Tracing noble...
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/debug.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/events.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/util.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/peripheral.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/service.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/characteristic.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/descriptor.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/debug.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/events.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/util.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/peripheral.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/service.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/characteristic.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
File not found or not accessible: /Users/user/Code/app/src/descriptor.js. Requested by /Users/user/Code/app/node_modules/noble/lib/noble.js
Tracing debug...
Tracing events...
Tracing util...
Tracing peripheral...
```

I can't seem to get it to link to noble's dependencies correctly.

This seems like it should be obvious (to someone) but for the life of me... I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you check if the version of **au cli** you are using is capable of using command `au import [packageNameHere]`? If not, you can upgrade to use it.

Comment: Are those really dependencies of noble?  I don't see them listed as dependencies in their package.json below.
 I'm unfamiliar with that library, but the reason I looked at their dependencies is your trace output shows it looking for those files in your source directory, almost as if it's something your app is supposed to supply as opposed to a build/compile dependency of noble itself. https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble/blob/master/package.json